# Can I assign multiple threads to a code section in OpenMP?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I'm looking for a way to execute sections of code in parallel using multiple threads for each section. For example, if I have 16 threads and two tasks, I want 8 threads each to simultaneously execute those two tasks. OpenMP has several constructs (`section`, `task`) that execute general code in parallel, but they are single-threaded. In my scenario, using `section` or `task` would result in one thread executing each of the two tasks, while 14 threads sit idly by.

Is something like that even possible with OpenMP? If so, how do I do it, and if not, what can I use for that purpose?

Thanks for your time!

**edit 2:**

Let me expand on this question with an example code:

```cpp
class some_class{
    void task(){
        cout<<"Entering the task method"<<endl;
        #pragma openmp parallel for
            for(int i=0; i < large_matrix.rows(); i++){
                 perform_thread_safe_operation(large_matrix.getRow(i));
            }
    }

    matrix large_matrix;
};


void main(){
    //I have 16 cores, so I want to spawn 16 threads
     some_class o1;
     some_class o2;
    // I want 8 of the 16 threads to execute this line:
    o1.task();
    // and 8 remaining threads to execute this line:
    o2.task();
}
```

Comment: I just updated my answer with a solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this using nested parallel regions.

```
omp_set_nested(1);

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
{
    if (omp_get_thread_num() == 0){
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
        {

            //  Task 0

        }
    }else{
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
        {

            //  Task 1

        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could do it like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(16)
{
    if (omp_get_thread_num() < 8){
        //  Task 0
    }else{
        //  Task 1
    }
}
```

Note, this code will not work if OpenMP decides to use fewer than 16 threads. You will have to insert your own cleanup code for that.

EDIT: In response to your update:

```
class some_class{
    void task(){
        cout<<"Entering the task method"<<endl;

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8)
        for(int i=0; i < large_matrix.rows(); i++){
            perform_thread_safe_operation(large_matrix.getRow(i));
        }
    }

    matrix large_matrix;
};


void main(){

    omp_set_nested(1);

    //I have 16 cores, so I want to spawn 16 threads
     some_class o1;
     some_class o2;

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
   {
       if (omp_get_thread_num() == 0){
           // I want 8 of the 16 threads to execute this line:
           o1.task();
       }else{
           // and 8 remaining threads to execute this line:
           o2.task();
       }
   }
}
```